# "]>" characters showing at top of Magento after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, upgrade

I upgraded from 1.7 to 1.9.1.1 for the most part successfully. Only one thing: there are these characters showing at the top of every page on the frontend: ]>

Any idea what might be causing this? I cleared the cache, logged out and back in to admin, etc.

Comment: you forgot that text in a class file somewhere.

Comment: why would it show only after the upgrade, but not before? any idea on how to identify where it is in the code?

Comment: runic ascii art, you have been hacked by norse nerds https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_(letter)

Comment: nicolalias , i'm not following...

Answer (score 2):

Invalid CDATA closing parameter maybe?

Comment: why would it show only after the upgrade, but not before? any idea on how to identify where it is in the code?

Comment: It's difficult to say without seeing your source, some CDATA has been added to versions later than 1.7 such as Mage.Cookies.path. As it appears on every page, best place to look is in your head.phtml and header.phtml files.

Comment: Yes it seems to be coming from the head.phtml according to the template hints. It is not raw text in that file, I think it is being outputted from the command <?php echo $this->getCssJsHtml() ?> . Where does it pull the HTML for that ? Here is the bad text showing up on the frontend: "<!--[if <!--[if (gte IE 9) | (IEMobile)]><!-->]>"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @IsaacY You should check your layout files, in your theme and the base theme. You probably have an xml tag like: `<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>` that was written incorrectly.

Comment: I'd have commented instead of answering @7ochem but I don't have the reputation, so what did you want me to do, not help? In a forum which focused on one helping another? <div>......Also dan above raises a good point.

Comment: @Stefkay 7ochem's comment was not intended in a bad way. The comment is just an *auto-comment* that gets added during [posts reviews](http://magento.stackexchange.com/review). There is also [a script](http://stackapps.com/q/2116) for [SE] sites that can be used to add comments semi-automatically. These comments just help other reviewers know that a post was reviewed, and can help mods turn such answers to comments if need be, instead of an answer getting deleted.